# ispunct() not removing commas in the middle of a string

Tags: c++, string, formatting, ifstream

I have a string that consists of:

```
UNIX is basically a simple operating system, but you have to be a genius to understand the simplicity.
```

I have the following code that is supposed to strip this string of all punctuation. The test variable is my string:

```
 if(std::ispunct(test[test.length()-1]))
    {
        test.erase(test.length()-1, 1);
    }
```

However when I output this string again after this function I have the following:

```
UNIX is basically a simple operating system, but you have to be a genius to understand the simplicity
```

For some reason the ispunct function is able to strip the period but not the comma. Why is it behaving in this manner? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is bad code if test was empty string (i.e. length was 0)

Comment: @franji1 I have code prior that tests for the case of an empty string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you're only doing this for `test[test.length()-1]` (the last character in the string). There's no comma there, just the period.

Comment: doh! I see it now, I guess my question is what is the best method to test the whole string? Is a string iterator appropriate or should I just use a simple for loop?

Comment: @NicYoung: No need for an explicit `for`-loop. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7801686/ispunct-not-removing-commas-in-the-middle-of-a-string/7801876#7801876) for a neat way to achieve this.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you are looking for the [`remove_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) [algorithm](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) (along with the [`ispunct`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/ispunct) [predicate](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Predicate)).

#### N.B:

> A call to `remove` is typically followed by a call to a container's [`erase`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/erase) method, which erases the unspecified values and reduces the *physical* size of the container to match its new *logical* size.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string dmr = "UNIX is basically a simple operating system, but you have to be a genius to understand the simplicity.";
    auto last = std::remove_if(dmr.begin(), dmr.end(), ispunct);
    dmr.erase(last, dmr.end());
    std::cout << dmr << std::endl;
}
```

[See it run!](http://ideone.com/Blrt3T)

Comment: Very nice, I did not know about remove_if. I will have to try it in my code. I am glad you got the reference. RIP dmr.

Comment: I get an error with this code it says `No matching function for call to 'remove_if'`

Comment: @bobthemac: Apologies, I'd missed the `algorithm` header. Fixed